# Networking issues - Ubuntu 16 home server network

Tags: networking, network-shares, home-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I just setup an ubuntu server machine I'm having issues connecting to it on my home network.. I can connect to it just fine via ssh from a mac but pinging it results in a timeout. Tried another local machine (windows) and still the ping fails.

The ubuntu machine appears to be configured correctly, it can ping all the other machines on the network, have checked firewall rules and ip/dns settings etc.

Out of ideas..

Please advise!

Comment: So basically what isn't working is just the ping?

Comment: So far the only thing that's working is me connecting to it via SSH. I want to setup a file sharing network (have samba all setup) but connecting to the ubuntu machine smb://serverIP/sharedfolder doesn't work

Comment: Is ufw is on at the ubuntu server? if so, what rules are enabled? Or maybe try disabling it for a while and see what changes

Comment: ufw is disabled:
    adrian@server:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
  
    Status: inactive
    adrian@server:~$ 

iptables are default to accept